# How to check a rule in windows firewall?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2, firewall, windows-firewall

I would like to check if a port is open in the Windows firewall.

I found this way using netsh:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="My rule"
```

which will return if the rule exists or not...

But, depending on Windows language, this will return different messages. I am trying to solve this in a better way. I would like to have a result `Yes` or `No`, `True` or `False`, not a localized string.

Do you have any tips??

Comment: what if there would be a third-party monitor ?

also "advfirewall" AFAIR is introduced in Vista or Win7, in 2000/XP there was no such command AFAIR

Comment: There is an api. Have you searched for it?

Comment: Try this [Using the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security scripting API and Delphi](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2013/11/21/using-the-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-scripting-api-and-delphi/)

Answer (score 3):

AS: the "advfirewall" command and underlying service were introduced in Windows Vista.  Windows 2000/XP do not have it and to support it you should use different interfaces.

Same goes for the computers with third-party, non-Microsoft firewalls installed (as part of antivirus suite for example).

In general on Vista+ you should obtain INetFwRules COM object, then enumerate all the rules in it, and check every rule if it covers the port you are about.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365345.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365362.aspx

Follows example to obtain and enumerate the rules
https://theroadtodelphi.com/2013/11/21/using-the-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-scripting-api-and-delphi/#Enumerating Firewall Rules

```
var
 CurrentProfiles : Integer;
 fwPolicy2       : OleVariant;
 RulesObject     : OleVariant;
 rule            : OleVariant;
 oEnum           : IEnumvariant;
 iValue          : LongWord;

  fwPolicy2   := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RulesObject := fwPolicy2.Rules;
  CurrentProfiles := fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;

  .....

  Writeln('Rules:');

  oEnum         := IUnknown(Rulesobject._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, rule, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    if (rule.Profiles And CurrentProfiles)<>0 then
    begin
        Writeln('  Rule Name:          ' + rule.Name);
        Writeln('   ----------------------------------------------');
        Writeln('  Description:        ' + rule.Description);
        Writeln('  Application Name:   ' + rule.ApplicationName);
        Writeln('  Service Name:       ' + rule.ServiceName);

        if (rule.Protocol = NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP) or (rule.Protocol = NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP) then
        begin
          Writeln('  Local Ports:        ' + rule.LocalPorts);
          Writeln('  Remote Ports:       ' + rule.RemotePorts);
          Writeln('  LocalAddresses:     ' + rule.LocalAddresses);
          Writeln('  RemoteAddresses:    ' + rule.RemoteAddresses);
        end;

    .....

  end;
```

OTOH using static binding rather than OleVariant should be faster and more reliable, check  https://github.com/yypbd/yypbd-Delphi-HeaderPorting/tree/master/example/FirewallExample